# What Wrong --> Error: No named parameter with the name 'autovalidate'

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, mobile

Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/material_dropdown_formfield-0.1.9/lib/material_dropdown_formfield.dart:124:13: Error: No named parameter with the name 'autovalidate'.
autovalidate: autovalidate,
^^^^^^^^^^^^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1156
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 32s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Can  you include your code-snippet

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a quite old package which is also discontinued and no more maintained. Please use `DropdownButtonFormField` instead from the flutter framework. You can get same result with `DropdownButtonFormField` too.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(children: <Widget>[
    DropdownButtonFormField(
      items: <DropdownMenuItem>[
        // Put widgets in the drop down menu here
      ],
    )
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for everyone! Your with help it was easy to understand what should I change.